# Can I create entire CRUD operation using REACT JS without node JS?

Tags: reactjs

Node JS is required to persorm a CRUD operation using REACTJS? I have tried many solutions but may be I am worng or unable to create it.

Comment: What solutions have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial might help you:[ReactJS Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBws8MSXN7A&t=4952s)

Here Brad created a complete todo app without any backend. Furthermore, if you want to store data, you can use local storage.